# Adding an image only if tier price is shown

Tags: image

I have a table which show the associated products. Some of these products have special tier price (buy 10 and get 10% off). I want to display a sale image if a tier price is shown however i am not very experienced with php so i am struggling a bit.

I tried

```
    <td class="a-left">
        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
        <br>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item)?> 
        <img src="/skin/frontend/base/default/images/low_price.png" alt="low price icon">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
```

But that just show the icon on every product even without a tier price. So i figured i would need an IF statement to check if the product has a tier price and if true then display the image. So i tried this.

```
<td class="a-left">
                <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                <br>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item)?> 
                <?php if ($this->getTierPriceHTML = True): ?>
                <img src="/skin/frontend/base/default/images/low_price.png" alt="low price icon"> <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
```

But that just had exactly the same outcome (image displayed on all products). I am not sure what else to try so if you could help it would be brilliant.

Thanks!!!

Comment: where you do this code???

Comment: in grouped.phtml

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $_item is a loaded product then use:

```
<?php if ( $_item->getTierPrice()): ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/low_price.png');?>" alt="low price icon">
<?php endif; ?>
```

and if $_item is not a fully loaded then use:

```
<?php 
   $_product =  $_item->getProduct(); 
   // OR
  // $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
   // Use whichever works for you.
 if ( $_product->getTierPrice()): ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/low_price.png');?>" alt="low price icon">
<?php endif; ?>
```

also consider how the **image url** is obtained from skin folder.

Comment: it still just adding the image to all products in the table. instead of just the ones with tier prices

Comment: is `$_item` a loaded product?

Comment: please check the updated answer